# Fastest way to simplify large fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, fractions

Suppose we have a large fraction like this

$\frac{2002}{429}$

which we could simplify by e.g. using the euclidean algorithm to find out the GCD. but is there kind of like a "trick" to find out the most simplified fraction for this in the fastest way possible?

Comment: If you know one of the two numbers has a factorization into a small number of factors then maybe, but gcd is logarithmic in a+b so it is super fast already, why do u want something even faster? As an aside, the problem can be reduced to finding the gcd, so you can just ask if good gcd algorithms exist under specific constraints instead.

Comment: well, in fact I was kind of just wondering if there was some secret trick that was faster than the euclidean algorithm :D at least a trick that could be applied under certain circumstances. Seems like its not the case?

Comment: @LinShao The Euclidean algorithm is known to be fast so I don't think you'll find a better method for hand calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a faster algorithm, (maybe this is a question for the CS SE is you are looking for a computer solution), but I would first write out the factors of each number that I can most clearly see:
$$
\frac{2002}{429}=\frac{2\cdot1001}{3\cdot143}=\frac{2\cdot7\cdot143}{3\cdot143}=\frac{2\cdot7}{3}=\frac{14}{3}
$$
and we have it. This particular example didn't have many steps, and essentially reverted to finding the GCD, but aside from a technique like this, there is no "trick" for factoring. In fact, there is no known way to quickly factorize large numbers (if you are more interested in this topic, look into Cryptography).

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you for the input. I guess I should be focusing on this particular part of "the factors that one can most clearly see" - e.g., that 1001 has a factor of 7. How did you find that so fast, and is there any trick to at least train that a little? :D and yep, I'm talking manual computation rather than with a PC

Comment: @LinShao In my case, I just already know that $1001=7\cdot 11\cdot13$, because that's the kind of trivia that you pick up as you go.

Comment: I'm sure you are familiar with all the factorization tricks for 3, 6, 9, etc. 7 is a little harder, and usually try to reduce the number by large factors of 7. $$1001=700+301 \to 301=70*4+21\to21$$ which is clearly divisible by 7. Hope this example helps.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks to both of you, I think I grasped the concept :)